# Simulating a transfer function in Simulink

Tags: matlab, controls, simulink, transfer-function

I decided to learn simulink and matlab since I'm interested in control engineering, been trying to solve some simple problems and this one in particular has been quite troublesome. Can anyone point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

This is what I've been trying to simulate:

[image: What I'm trying to simulate]

This is what I've done in simulink:

[image: What I've tried on simulink]

Quite unsure about the results of the simulation.

I solved that so I have values for T but still simulating it isn't as simple as it seemed. For stability 0 < T < 0.2 if T > 0.2 it's unstable

Well I expected a different answer for the poles given the T value I got, not sure what I'm looking for though.